# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse when server redirects to unknown location

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-401

I am trying to use HttpWebRequest.GetResponse where the server is making 302 redirect to another unknown location.

if the redirected target is known let it be `www.xyz.com` so we can use a configurationCache as follows

```
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(new Uri("http://xyz.com"), "Basic", netWorkCredential);
```

I got some information from this([building a credentialcache for httpwebrequest when redirection is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918682/building-a-credentialcache-for-httpwebrequest-credentials-when-redirects-are-ukn)) which apparently not working.

But if the target is unknown, I am getting a `401 Unauthorized` error. 
There is another option I had from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx), getting the Location from Headers and making another call.

Do I have any other options here.? Please let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use get the new location from the location header in the response and then make a fresh request to the new URL. This is how browser works. When it recieves HTTP status code 302 and 301(moved permanently), it makes a fresh request for the new location.

Comment: +1 for the info. And thats what we would be doing in the worst case. But, is there any way for doing in a single call?

Comment: I think your problem lies in where you are redirected to some new location, and you need to be authenticated before you access the resource.
Thats why I see you building a credential cached(key value pair: Domain, Credential). Even if you use, the above mentioned process, you may get 401 unauthorized error if the resource needs authentication