# Passing current windows authentication credentials when redirect user to different page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, windows-authentication, credentials

I currently have 2 ASP .NET sites running on the same IIS server, both sites are using windows authentication. When I redirect users from one site to another, the users are asked to re-enter their username and password, even though they are using the same user/pass to login into both site.

Is it possible to pass the credentials when doing the redirection so that user only have to login once?

I have found a somewhat related question here:

[Building a CredentialCache for HttpWebRequest.Credentials when redirects are uknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918682/building-a-credentialcache-for-httpwebrequest-credentials-when-redirects-are-ukn)

But that method only allow me to send request from one side to another instead of a full redirect.

Comment: You could use session to do this, although its not really secure. Better would be to use proper authentication in IIS and grab what you need from the code behind n each application

Comment: @user4663200 I'm currently using authentication for both sites, if users type in the URL of site 2 manually then they will still be asked to login. The problem is I need to find a way so that users are not prompted for password if they had already logged in for site 1.

Comment: I think this could be helpful for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825205(v=cs.10).aspx

Comment: @user4663200 Unfortunately that link did not give me much useful information. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Just an update, I finally gave up on this issue and decided to combine my 2 sites into one. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works so I'll go with that for now.